Напишите программу, которая запрашивает целое число и печатает английское порядковое числительное
int x;
cin >> x;
int mod10 = (x % 10), mod100 = (x % 100);
string suf;
if (mod100 == 11 || mod100 == 12 ||mod100 == 13)
{  suf ="th";
    cout << (x) << suf << endl;   
} else if (mod10 == 1) {
     suf ="st";
    cout << (x) << suf << endl;
}
else if (mod10 == 2) {
     suf = "nd";
    cout << (x) << suf << endl;
}
else if (mod10 == 3) {
      suf = "rd";
    cout << (x) << suf << endl;
}
else  {  suf ="th"; 
    cout << (x) << suf << endl;
}


Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе

Это задание. А вопрос-то в чем? :)
